# Multiple files being uploaded in first foreach loop causing an error with file upload system

Tags: php, file, file-upload, foreach

I have a form that allows 1 to multiple file uploads. I just noticed that when making multiple file uploads with a submission there is an error.

`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

For this line:

`foreach ($filename as $indFile) {`

The files upload, but it is effecting other areas in the file due to the error.

I added in `var_export($filename);` to do some debugging and this printed out:

`array ( 0 => 'aboveFold.PNG', 1 => 'afterglow.png', )0<br /> <b>Warning</b>: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

From this `var_export` what I gather is the file upload is occuring through the first loop and then when it loops again, it creates a 0.

Does anyone have any suggestions that will fix this multiple file upload issue, while preserving the form to work with a single or no file.

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    foreach($file['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) { //empty string
            if($file['error'][$key] != 4) { //error code is not #4
                $fu = new fileUpload();
                $filename = $fu->upload();
                //var_export($filename);
                $out = (count($filename) > 1 ? 'Multiple files were' : 'A file was'). '  uploaded. You can download ' . (count($filename) > 1 ? 'them' : 'the file'). ' from:</ul>';
                foreach ($filename as $indFile) {
                    //$template = str_replace("{filename}", "A file was uploaded. You can download the file from: <a href='https://mbkit.com/php/uploads/{$indFile}'>{$indFile}</a>", $template);
                    //print_r($template);
                    $out .= "<li><a href='https://mbkit.com/php/uploads/{$indFile}'>{$indFile}</a></li>";
                }
                $out .= '</ul>';
                $template = str_replace("{filename}", $out, $template);

                //echo "name is NOT empty AND error is NOT 4";
            } else { //error code IS #4
                //echo "error code is 4";
            }
        } else {
            //echo "name is empty!";
            $template = str_replace("{filename}", '', $template);
        }
    }
}
clearstatcache();
```

Comment: Tyre this foreach($_FILE as $file){//save file using move_file_upload($file['temp_name'],$savefilepath) function in PHP }.

Comment: Doing this `$_FILE as $file` results in an undefined variable error.

Comment: Tyre this foreach($_FILES as $file){//save file using move_file_upload($file['file']['temp_name'],$savefilepath) function in PHP }.

Comment: Check new answer

Comment: @RishabhRawat I don't have issues getting the files to upload. There are errors that occur because of the 0 being produced.